# Unable to Achieve a "Silent Shutdown"

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, boot, shutdown, reboot

**The Problem**

I've been following the Arch guide for a [silent boot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/silent_boot) experience and have been successful at silencing all boot messages. Unfortunately, it seems this doesn't apply to shutdowns/restarts and I'm unable to find any documentation or solution that removes the single line that keeps plaguing my nearly perfectly silent boot up/shutdown process.

As I said, the bootup process is completely clean and silent. When attempting to shutdown or restart the system however, I will get a line that says:

[[xxxx.yyyy] reboot: Power down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANgpM.jpg)

or

[[xxxx.yyyy] reboot: Restarting system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYHB7.png)

I have attempted using various different kernel parameters and settings that I could find through searching the web or just tinkering with what I already knew but no matter what... this message persists. I assume its coming from systemd or the kernel itself but at this point I don't know and am just getting frustrated that something that should be simple is so obtuse/non-intuitive. If anybody could help me identify definitively where this message is coming from, or even better how to disable it, I would be infinitely grateful.

**Current Configuration**

I've gone through many different kernel parameters/configurations, but here is what I currently have (producing the same shutdown/restart messages in screenshots above) in case there is something obviously missing or might prove useful otherwise.

*OS:

> Arch Linux

*KERNEL AND SYSTEMD VERSION:

> 5.15.2-arch1-1

> systemd 249 (249.6-3-arch)

*KERNEL PARAMETERS:

> rw quiet loglevel=0 rd.systemd.show_status=no rd.udev.log_priority=0 vt.global_cursor_default=0 nowatchdog modprobe.blacklist=iTCO_wdt

*MKINITCPIO HOOKS:

> HOOKS=(base udev autodetect modconf block filesystems keyboard)

*KERNEL.PRINTK VALUES:

> /etc/sysctl.d/20-quiet-printk.conf contains the line
> "kernel.printk = 0 0 0 0"